# How to programatically clear the recycle bin under Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, c, windows, winapi

In case I want to programatically clear the recycle bin under Windows, how to implement that?

Does `IFileOperation` help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SHEmptyRecycleBin()` function from `shell32.dll` library to achieve this.

Comment: @Sughakar When your answer contains a link to an identical question, it's better to vote to close as a duplicate. It you cannot vote, then leave a comment to the effect that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Sure David, Thanks for your inputs.i will follow it.

Answer (score 2):

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    enum RecycleFlags : uint
    {
        SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x00000001,
        SHERB_NOPROGRESSUI = 0x00000002,
        SHERB_NOSOUND = 0x00000004
    }

    [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern uint SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr hwnd, string pszRootPath, RecycleFlags dwFlags);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        uint result = SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr.Zero, null, 0);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            //OK
        }
    }
}
```